# Are Heart Points available in the REST API?

Tags: google-fit-sdk

Are Heart Points available in the REST API for reading?  IF so, how do we get to them?  I'm not seeing the documentation data.  Thanks.

Eric

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [**Users.dataSources.datasets**](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/datasets/get) API endpoint. You can grab the hearts points merged from all data points by querying the dataSourceId "derived:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_minutes". It returns a JSON object with an array called "points". You'll find each heart point in that list and if you drill down further for each heart point you'll get the derived source.

The endpoint takes the form:
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/dataSourceId/datasets/datasetId

Replace the following in the URL above:

dataSourceId: derived:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_minutes

datasetId: The ID is formatted like: "startTime-endTime" where startTime and endTime are 64 bit integers.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on WiteCastle's answer, this datasource will provide you with the heart points.

```
"derived:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_minutes"
```

You will need to specify a timeframe denoted by the datasetId parameter which is a start time and and an end time in epoch time with nanoseconds format, e.g.:

```
1607904000000000000-1608057778000000000
```

The json response includes an array of points, essentially each time the sensor detected the user's activity. The 'heart points' are accessible within each point's "fpVal". Example of a point is below:

```
{
    "startTimeNanos": "1607970900000000000",
    "endTimeNanos": "1607970960000000000",
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.heart_minutes",
    "originDataSourceId": "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_rate_bpm",
    "value": [
        {
            "fpVal": 2,    <--- 2 heart points recorded during this activity
            "mapVal": []
        }
    ],
    "modifiedTimeMillis": "1607976569329"
},
```

To get the heart points for today, specify the timeframe (00:00-23:59 in epcoch format), then loop through each point adding up all the "fpVal" values.